# how to convert array of arrays to array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, lodash, linq.js

I am trying to create a json file to test out some react-native [map polygon functionality](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/Overlays.js). I have geoJson available from a project using leaflet maps. I need to format the lat/lng points. I have drilled down from the top level-geometry-coordinates. but I am stuck on what to do next. Since i only need the end result for testing any library can be used in the plunker to get the desired result.

here is where i am at.

```
[
[
    [
        -106.75845,
        34.659846
    ],
    [
        -106.81188,
        34.649485
    ],
    [
        -106.80648,
        34.646378
    ],
    [
        -106.75845,
        34.659846
    ]
],
[
    [
        -106.70432,
        34.650473
    ],
    [
        -106.79663,
        34.720663
    ],
    [
        -106.7278,
        34.637498
    ],
    [
        -106.70432,
        34.650473
    ]
]
```

]

this is the what i need the end result to look like. [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Okn4PpBSAaM43NZjuCO6?p=catalogue)

```
  // desired result
  var result = [[{
                    latitude: 0,
                    longitude: 0
                }, {
                    latitude: 0,
                    longitude: 0
                }, {
                    latitude: 0,
                    longitude: 0
                }], [{
                    latitude: 0,
                    longitude: 0
                }, {
                    latitude: 0,
                    longitude: 0
                }, {
                    latitude: 0,
                    longitude: 0
                }]];
```

Comment: This appears too simple (basic JS). What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HSbprm4bhtbgIGTpZUSJ?p=preview)

```
obj = obj.map(function(innerArray){
   return innerArray.map(function(value){ 
      return {latitude:value[0], longitude:value[1]}  ;
   });
});
console.log(obj);
```